# Big O Notation: Nested Loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
     sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m*m; j++)
           sum++;
```

Been trying to figure out the time complexity of this algorithm with Big-O Notation. 
I've only found out that  1- first loop counts as O(m) and 2- Second loop counts as O(m^2). But I have a single problem. Does this nested loop counts as O(m^3) or do I have to take the fastest growing function as a basis and say that this loop counts as O(m^2) ?

Comment: It's multiplied, so `O(m^3)`. The same way as simple loop is `O(n)` but two such nested loops are `O(n*n)`

Comment: The outer loop is O(m), the inner loop is O(m^2), the whole is O(m x m^2) = O(m^3)

Answer (score 2):

You have to count how many times `sum++` will effectively be performed, and not speculate about the growth of the functions.

Every time the inner loop is called, it executes `sum++` exactly m² times.

And the inner loop is executed exactly m times by the outer loop, hence in total m³ `sum++`.

Needless to say, O(m³).

Answer (score 1):

What helped me in university, just think of an example - e.g. 2.

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
for(int j = 0; j<4; j++)
```

So the loop runs 8 times, which is `2 * 4` times, which is `8`, which is `2*2*2`, or `2³`.

Comment: Some indentation and explanation more related to the question would help (m^2...)

Comment: @YvesDaoust No. Especially for that explanation, and OP is seemingly a beginner.

Comment: @e2-e4: the OP did indent the code himself. I agree that the explanation is weak, as "8 times" is announced with no justification, then empirically factored to 2³, whichis cheating.

Comment: I actually wanted to show OP a way to verify his assumption. That my explanation isn't strong is true though.

Comment: This "experimental" method can only work if you observe the inner working of the algorithm, because the single relation `f(2)=8` tells you nothing useful about `f`. For instance, this could match `F(m)=2m², m+6, 2^(m²-1)`...

Comment: I agree that this can be used to validate a formula obtained by reasoning. But only if you get the exact count, not a big-O estimate.

Comment: Indentation or a semicolon would help a lot to understand this answer. I can't tell whether this was meant as `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) /* do something */ }` or `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++); for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++);`.